# Service not available in c2dm

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I am running a sample push notification example.I have done the c2dm signup and got an email.But the problem is when i run the program logcat shows registration id as null and error as "Service not available".
Please help me.
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has happened in my application as well. I find that when the emulator starts you often need to let it run the intent (i.e. your main activity) and then exit the application. Start the application again from the emulator and it seems to work for me. A few things to double check while your at it:
1. Did you declare your receivers in your manifest file?
2. Did you use the proper package name in your manifest?
3. Did you run the google api (level 8) AVD
4. Did you add your push sender account to the emulator?

hope this helps!